Unexpected output because of NewExtrusion method in Revit
Below is the Revit api I am using
Extrusion voidExtrusion = familyDoc.FamilyCreate.NewExtrusion(
    false, // Create a void
    curveArrArray,
    sketchPlane,
    holeDepth // Depth of the extrusion
);

Also I have set cut to geometry
// Enable geometry cutting if supported
Parameter voidCutsGeometryParam = voidExtrusion.get_Parameter(BuiltInParameter.VOID_CUTS_GEOMETRY);
if (voidCutsGeometryParam != null && !voidCutsGeometryParam.IsReadOnly)
{
    voidCutsGeometryParam.Set(1);
}

Then also I am unable to cut through the cube that I have already created. What can I do so that the newly created extrusion will cut the geometry ?
I have tried using the NewExtrusionForm Revit api
public Form NewExtrusionForm(
    bool isSolid,
    ReferenceArray profile,
    XYZ direction
)

In this I am getting the exception as
Autodesk.Revit.Exceptions InvalidOperationException - The attempted operation is not permitted in this type of family
Is their any other way where I can see one created cube family -> edit family -> Create a hole to that family.

Here is a sample using NewExtrusionForm to create a sloped wall.
